# Create a TIFF Group 4 with 300dpi Black and white in swift

Tags: ios, swift, tiff

I´m trying to create a TIFF format  image on swift IOS in order to send the result by email. I saw here how to create a TIFF but it was not possible for me to set the TIFF file to CCITT Group 4 (1 bit color depth, b&w) format with 300dpi. Any help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It would be useful if we had an example of what you've already tried to do in order to solve this problem.

Comment: I want to generate a TIFF file from a UIImage in swift. BUT the TIFF should be compressed on Group4 and with resolution 300dpi. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to look outside the Apple frameworks for 1 bit-per-pixel image support. CGImage doesn't support 1bpp bitmaps, so even if you set up ImageIO to write a monochrome TIFF what you actually get is an 8bpp grayscale TIFF.

You should look into including tifflib and calling that from your Swift code.  Here's a GitHub project with a script that fetches and generates iOS static libraries for tifflib:

https://github.com/ashtons/libtiff-ios.git

While it doesn't answer the "in Swift" part of the question, there's an answer to this question over here that covers calling tifflib from iOS:

[How do I write a 1bpp tiff with libtiff on iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21916113/how-do-i-write-a-1bpp-tiff-with-libtiff-on-ios/30282161)

You can either create an ObjC file using the answer from that question that bridges to tifflib (that's what I did), or adapt that code to Swift.